# AWS_S3 ruby gem Timeout Error execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am processing some video with ffmpeg and then firing the video up to S3 with the [aws_s3 gem](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/).  I use the following code:

```
S3Object.store("testme.mp4", open(file), 'blah', :access => :public_read)
```

Everything works great but with files of 1GB and over I receive the following error:

```
"Timeout::Error: execution expired".
```

This only happens after ffmpeg has processed the file however.  If I send the file on its own, without processing, then everything is fine.

Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Thanks,

SLothistype

Answer (score 5):

I have run into this problem, and unfortunately had to monkey patch the AWS::S3::Connection::create_connection method, so I could increase the read_timeout.

If you implement the method yourself, you would set

```
http.read_timeout = 300 # or something else higher
```

I originally found this from Pivotal Labs, Inc. They are pretty well respected and basically were saying "this is not a great solution, but the aws_s3 gem doesn't expose anything better."

Comment: Tried that but with little success... I might hack the gem.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: 'Hacking' aka Monkeypatching, is exactly what I had to do. The problem is you are timing out when uploading large files, which happens on your end. This is not the MOST elegant solution, but unless you want to roll your own service and accompany it with a gem, it might be the necessary evil :(

Comment: Where exactly would you place your code snippet for this to work? I have no idea where the http variable is coming from in your example..

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to set the `:http_read_timeout` is while initializing `Aws::S3::Client`.

```rb
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#initialize-instance_method
s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: region_name,
  credentials: credentials,
  http_read_timeout: 300,
)

# Instead of open(file) in code from the OP's code
File.open('/source/file/path', 'rb') do |file|
  # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#put_object-instance_method
  s3_client.put_object(bucket: 'bucket-name', key: 'testme.mp4', body: file)
end
```