# Timeout::Error: execution expired with Capistrano/Rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano, rubber

We have been using the rubber gem to deploy to AWS for months and we are now suddenly getting a `Timeout::Error: execution expired error` with Capistrano. I've tried downgrading `net-ssh` to 2.7 and that didn't help. I believe the old net-ssh 2.8 has been resolved for awhile now and we are use 2.9.1 (and have been for awhile).

I'm able to SSH into the instances with no problems. Has anyone ran into similar issues? Is there something else I should check that could lead me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I also get Timeout::Error: execution expired when trying to run rubber's bootstrap and refresh commands. I'm wondering if it would be faster to just redeploy everything and switch the Elastic IP but don't want to continue to run into this problem down the road.

Comment: There were some quite a few passenger processes running. I killed all of those. There as still PassengerWatchdog(VMSize 218.4) PassengerHelperAgent( VMSize 494.4) and PassengerLoggingAgent 232.8) running. The load average is also low load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.03 since pretty much nothing is currently running or up

Answer (score 1):

Did something in the network change, DNS name, elastic IP, etc? See links below for users that have had similar problems:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubber-ec2/aK2RqUO7x-M/pzM0S-azDCIJ

[Rubber and Amazon EC2 hosting issue (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188460/rubber-and-amazon-ec2-hosting-issue-netsshauthenticationfailed-root)

https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/141

Also, if your files sizes are too large, perhaps it is timing out during the upload. See this link for an example of how to increase the timeout:

[AWS_S3 ruby gem Timeout Error execution expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609831/aws-s3-ruby-gem-timeout-error-execution-expired)